# Unable to Seek on Full Screen Videos in Chrome/Chrome Beta

Tags: applications, chrome-for-android, video

So I have an odd issue that I haven't been able to find a fix for. When I'm watching a video in Chrome (or Chrome Beta), if I go full screen, whenever I try to seek to a different time in the video, the video does not load/freezes. I can watch the video not in full screen and seek through it just fine, as soon as you go full screen (in portrait or landscape) seeking does not work.

However, this issue does not occur in the regular Internet browser. It also only occurs with a certain type of player, for instance, Vimeo does not have this issue. This issue used to only occur in Chrome Beta, but now it's occurring in both Chrome versions on Android.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling both versions of the app, as well as clearing cache/data for both versions of the app and neither has resolved it.

The device I'm using is a Galaxy S7 Edge on 6.0.1 (T-MO Variant)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How's your Internet connection? What if you wait a while after seeking (I mean like a good minute)?

Comment: @JohnRamos I have a gigabit connection,. It's definitely not internet speed, this doesn't occur in the regular Internet app, and it doesn't occur if I'm not full screen.

Comment: Can you give me one site the problem always occurs on (so I can test it)? Also try toggling data saver maybe? Clearing all of your site storage in Chrome?

Comment: This doesn't seem to happen on desktop mode for me  But I hardly watch videos.. You can verify and also see this to set Chrome into desktop mode permanently  http://android.stackexchange.com/a/154094/131553

Comment: I have checked again with a few you tube videos and it doesn't happen in desktop mode. You can verify and if this works for you will post ad am answer

Comment: Well i tried with latest Chrome beta and had no problems in mobile mode. - which site is giving you problems?  On the face of it looks like it is untapped to Chrome but can't be sure

Comment: Try this Google Chrome > Settings > Advanced > Accessibility > Force enable zoom. This may solve