# How decrease font or make text readable in Android Chrome?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, chrome-for-android, zooming, usability, browser

Output in Android Chrome where you see classroom not visible in timetable, but I see it with my PC. 
Portrait and landscape views have the same problem.

Fig. 1 Landscape view

[image]

Phone: Oneplus 2.
OS: OxygenOS 3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options inherent to Chrome

- By *Scaling* the text size to make it readable

Menu (upper right corner) → Settings →Accessibility option → Text Scaling

Of course, you may need to resize the text for other sites of text is too small for comfort

- By enabling *Force Zoom* -  useful if zoom by pinching is disabled

[image]

- Enabling *Desk Top* mode may also help pinch to zoom from Settings → Request desktop site. Related [How to make Google Chrome definitely remain as the desktop version?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/154077/131553)

Comment: Text scaling does not take immediate effect. Not after reloading neither. - - How does it behave in your phone?

Comment: It works immediately on applying on my device. I had tested and posted the answer. I am on Chrome `53.0.2785.124` Android 6.0.1. I don't know if it is related to the ROM that it is not working your case.// What about *desktop* mode?

Comment: No. Desktop does not help. My version is 53.0.2xxx.124. same as yours. I sent a ticket about the problem to google.

Comment: On second thoughts, is the font size not changing on *any* other site? Or particular to your work site? If it works for  other sites but not for work site, it means that your work site is not designed to *render properly on mobile devices* and it is not the fault of Chrome and you would need to check with the owners of the site. I have checked on multiple sites and it works fine , so I suspect it is the issue with the site

Comment: No, the problem is not with the site. I still see all sites in the same font size although I have 50% font scaling.

Comment: I see. This is the designed feature of Chrome and with the same version of Chrome if you can't change and I can, it probably some other problem (OS?) . You may consider *accepting* the answer, to help others in future, while you raised a ticket. Searching in OS forums may also help find reason or you can raise a ticket there too