# How can I force Chrome into loading Facebook as a desktop site by default?

Tags: chrome-for-android

I hate the Facebook messsenger app, so I ditched it. However, my current work-around is:

1. Open the messages tab on m.facebook.com
2. Wait for Play store to load
3. Close, enable desktop mode
   4, Go to the Messages tab again.

As per the title, how can I make Particular sites I.e. Facebook load desktop site by default (in chrome)?

*Note: I only want Facebook affected. Other sites are fine.*

Edit: No root, please. I don't have access to the stuff to root, and I just don't want to. Also, I want this for **Facebook** Only, which excludes Beeshyams related question. Sorry Beetroot!

Comment: [Related](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/154077/131553) - suggest you edit the title to prevent dupe closure

Comment: +1. Please see the first approach -it's for Unrooted Devices too ! But the key difference is you want it for a specific site. A cumbersome approach could be using that XDA method and then using Tasker to make FB specific changes?

Comment: It seems like upcoming Chrome versions will have such a feature: [Chrome for Android will soon add a permanent desktop mode toggle](https://www.xda-developers.com/chrome-for-android-add-permanent-desktop-mode-toggle/)