# Force desktop version of websites

Tags: browser

How to force desktop version of websites ?

Changing the user agent of the browser is useless.

Many sites steal your resolution info to shove the mobile version down your @$$

How to overcome that ?

I use Opera browser, for information sake. Altough I suppose the fix lays outside of the browser

Got Xposed

Answer (score 1):

Launching browser in desktop mode is related to the browser and not something that needs to be tweaked in Android OS. I have no idea for Opera, but for :

. Chrome - see [How to make Google Chrome definitely remain as the desktop version?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/154077/131553)

. Mozilla has [Desktop by default](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/desktop-by-default/) add-on

Comment: The question was more about "how to make it work" than "how to make it work permanently". But yeah, Chrome works much better. Been testing it, and it seems like pages actually obey the "Desktop version" order. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

Brave Browser allows one to force the desktop version. The setting is under settings->site settings.

Unfortunately it is missing per site choosing of desktop/mobile versions

Answer (score 0):

Well..using Android 7 and the latest Chrome version.. you just need to open the web site  http://m.version.com...

Then using the optios on the rigth top address bar you select the option Desktop Site...then the page is open in its original desktop layout as http://www.version.com...

Once in the desk top version, you just create the short cut of this page by adding it to the home screem..by selecting the option Add to Home screen in the address top rigth options menu...

Once the system add it to the home screen it just copy the actual address of the page added..which will be the desktop version..www.version.com..

So now every time you need to access the page, using this short cut, it will be in ist original layout www.version.com..

However, if you pretend to use this option to every page you view..it wiil no be a solution since you will end with a crowded home page...probably many pages to surfe the wanted page. Taking in consideration that most of the home pages hold at least 30 shortcut icons.....too many to be good.